# iOS:Get a dynamic number of subviews to take up maximum space in superview both horizontally and vertically

Tags: ios, swift

I have a superview with an arbitrary amount of subviews. The app I'm creating has the ability to continually add subviews into this superview. I want the subviews to fill as much space as possible like shown in the pictures below. These subviews will have an aspect ratio of 5:8

[image]
[image]

---

My idea was to add one horizontal stack view inside of a vertical stackview initially. The number of inner stackviews would be equal to a variable which is set to the max number of cards per row(which would be √(numberOfViews)). When the number of subviews becomes greater than this variable, I could add another inner stack view. I would have to keep track of each inner stackview and make sure they almost all contain the same number of elements

---

I'm wondering if there is an easier solution. Also the math for this solution does not work for the case of sideways orientation.

Comment: why you are not using collection view

Comment: @Sam - Collection view *may* work, but might be tough to implement. It is designed to flow the subviews (the cells), but scroll when there are too many to fit. Isn't your goal is to change the size of the subviews to fit the area?

Comment: @DonMag Yes that is my goal, the subviews should fill the maximum space possible within the superview while maintaining a 5:8 ratio and not overlapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounded like an interesting task, so I gave it a quick shot.

Here is one approach...

Think about the layout as columns and rows.

Start with all items (the added subviews) laid out in a single row, fitting the width of the container. Since the items are at a 5:8 ratio, we can calculate the height of the row.

- If the row height is less than the remaining vertical space, we can fit another row.

So, decrement the number of columns - which effectively moves one item down to the next row, and recalculate. Each time we decrement the columns, the items will get *wider*... which will also make them *taller*, so...

- Check again if we can fit another row.

Keep decrementing the number of columns until the rows are too tall to fit.

Here's an example with 7 items:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

At this point, the rows no longer fit in the container, so we know that 3-columns gives us the max item size.

We're not quite done yet though...

Depending on the number of items and the size / ratio of the container, we might not be getting the largest possible size.

Here is an example with just 2 items. With 2 columns, we can fit another row... but in doing so, the items become much wider and taller, and won't fit in a single column:

[image]
[image]

If we manually lay out 1 column x 2 rows, we get this:

[image]

Each item is obviously larger in this layout than two items side-by-side.

So, after running our "columns by rows" calc, we need to run a "rows by columns" calc. Same process, but start with all items in a single column... decrementing the number of rows until they no longer fit:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

With 4 rows, they fit, with 3 rows, they don't.

Now, we compare the max item size from the "columns by rows" calc with the max item size from the "rows by columns" calc, and use the larger result.

Here is a full example. All code (no `@IBOutlets` or `@IBActions`), so just add a new view controller and assign its custom class to `ArrangeViewController`:

```
//
//  ArrangeViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 11/02/19.
//

import UIKit

class ArrangeViewController: UIViewController {

    // Add a view button
    let addButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        v.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        v.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        v.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
        return v
    }()

    // Remove a view button
    let remButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        v.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        v.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        v.setTitle("Remove", for: .normal)
        return v
    }()

    // horizontal stackview to hold the buttons
    let btnsStack: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.axis = .horizontal
        v.alignment = .fill
        v.distribution = .fillEqually
        v.spacing = 20
        return v
    }()

    // view to hold the added views
    let innerContainerView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .clear
        v.clipsToBounds = true
        return v
    }()

    // view to hold the view holding the added views (allows us to center the resulting layout)
    let outerContainerView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .clear
        v.clipsToBounds = true
        return v
    }()

    // view to hold the outer container...
    let borderContainerView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .white
        return v
    }()

    // we'll be updating the .constant of these constraints
    var innerWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var innerHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue

        // add the buttons to the stack view
        btnsStack.addArrangedSubview(addButton)
        btnsStack.addArrangedSubview(remButton)

        // add inner container to outer container
        outerContainerView.addSubview(innerContainerView)

        // add outer container to border container
        borderContainerView.addSubview(outerContainerView)

        // add buttons stack to the view
        view.addSubview(btnsStack)

        // add border container to the view
        view.addSubview(borderContainerView)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        // initialize inner container width and height constraints
        innerWidthConstraint = innerContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.0)
        innerHeightConstraint = innerContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.0)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain buttons stack Top / Leading / Trailing with a little "padding"
            btnsStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btnsStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btnsStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            // buttons height to 35-pts (just for asthetics)
            btnsStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35.0),

            // constrain border container
            // 40-pts below buttons
            borderContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnsStack.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            // 20-pts from view bottom
            borderContainerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            // 60-pts Leading and Trailing
            borderContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 60.0),
            borderContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -60.0),

            // constrain outer container 5-pts on each side to match arranged view's view-to-view spacing
            outerContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: borderContainerView.topAnchor, constant: 5.0),
            outerContainerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: borderContainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5.0),
            outerContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: borderContainerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5.0),
            outerContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: borderContainerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5.0),

            // activate inner container width and height constraints
            innerWidthConstraint,
            innerHeightConstraint,

            // keep inner container centered inside outer container
            innerContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerContainerView.centerXAnchor),
            innerContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerContainerView.centerYAnchor),

        ])

        // add actions for the Add and Delete buttons
        addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        remButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(remTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
        }) { [unowned self] _ in
            self.arrangeViews()
        }

    }

    @objc func addTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {

        // instantiate a new custom view and add it to
        // the inner container view
        let v = MyView()
        innerContainerView.addSubview(v)
        v.theLabel.text = "\(innerContainerView.subviews.count)"

        // update the arrangement
        arrangeViews()

    }

    @objc func remTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {

        // if inner container has at least one custom view
        if let v = innerContainerView.subviews.last {

            // remove it
            v.removeFromSuperview()

            // update the arrangement
            arrangeViews()

        }

    }

    func arrangeViews() -> Void {

        // make sure there is at least 1 subview to arrange
        guard innerContainerView.subviews.count > 0 else { return }

        // init local vars to use
        // Note: making them all CGFLoats makes it easier to use in expressions - avoids a lot of casting CGFloat(var)

        var numCols: CGFloat = 0
        var numRows: CGFloat = 0

        var lastCols: CGFloat = 0
        var lastRows: CGFloat = 0
        var lastW: CGFloat = 0
        var lastH: CGFloat = 0

        var finalW: CGFloat = 0
        var finalH: CGFloat = 0
        var finalCols: CGFloat = 0
        var finalRows: CGFloat = 0

        var w: CGFloat = 0
        var h: CGFloat = 0

        // this is the frame we need to fit inside
        let containerWidth: CGFloat = outerContainerView.frame.size.width
        let containerHeight: CGFloat = outerContainerView.frame.size.height

        // number of views to arrange
        let numItems: CGFloat = CGFloat(innerContainerView.subviews.count)

        // first pass, we calculate based on converting columns to rows
        // start with 1 row containing all views (so, 10 views == 10 columns)

        numCols = numItems
        numRows = 1

        // get the width and height of a single item
        w = containerWidth / numCols
        h = w * 8.0 / 5.0

        // if the height of a single item (at 5:8 ratio) is too tall to fit
        // we need to start with the height of the container
        if h > containerHeight {
            h = containerHeight
            w = h * 5.0 / 8.0
        }

        // our while loop will manipulate these vars, so save each "last" value
        // inside the loop

        lastCols = numCols
        lastRows = numRows
        lastW = w
        lastH = h

        // while a single item height * number of rows is less than container height
        // AND number of columds is greater than 1
        // decrement the number of columns and re-calc
        // which will add a row if needed
        while h * numRows < containerHeight, numCols > 1 {
            lastCols = numCols
            lastRows = numRows
            lastW = w
            lastH = h
            numCols -= 1
            numRows = ceil(numItems / numCols)
            w = containerWidth / numCols
            h = w * 8.0 / 5.0
        }

        // we now have the size of a single item,
        // and the number of columns and rows,
        // based on columns-to-rows calculations,
        // so save them for comparison
        let pass1W: CGFloat = lastW
        let pass1H: CGFloat = lastH
        let pass1Cols: CGFloat = lastCols
        let pass1Rows: CGFloat = lastRows

        // second pass, we calculate based on converting rows to columns
        // start with 1 column containing all views (so, 10 views == 10 rows)

        numRows = numItems
        numCols = 1

        // get the width and height of a single item
        h = containerHeight / numRows
        w = h * 5.0 / 8.0

        // if the width of a single item (at 5:8 ratio) is too wide to fit
        // we need to start with the width of the container
        if w > containerWidth {
            w = containerWidth / numCols
            h = w * 8.0 / 5.0
        }

        // our while loop will manipulate these vars, so save each "last" value
        // inside the loop

        lastRows = numRows
        lastCols = numCols
        lastH = h
        lastW = w

        // while a single item width * number of columns is less than container width
        // AND number of rows is greater than 1
        // decrement the number of rows and re-calc
        // which will add a column if needed
        while w * numCols < containerWidth, numRows > 1 {
            lastRows = numRows
            lastCols = numCols
            lastH = h
            lastW = w
            numRows -= 1
            numCols = ceil(numItems / numRows)
            h = containerHeight / numRows
            w = h * 5.0 / 8.0
        }

        // we now have the size of a single item,
        // and the number of rows and columns,
        // based on rows-to-columns calculations,
        // so save them for comparison
        let pass2W: CGFloat = lastW
        let pass2H: CGFloat = lastH
        let pass2Cols: CGFloat = lastCols
        let pass2Rows: CGFloat = lastRows

        // if second pass item size is greater than first pass item size
        //   use second pass results
        // else
        //   use first pass results
        if pass2H * pass2W > pass1H * pass1W {
            finalW = pass2W
            finalH = pass2H
            finalCols = pass2Cols
            finalRows = pass2Rows
        } else {
            finalW = pass1W
            finalH = pass1H
            finalCols = pass1Cols
            finalRows = pass1Rows
        }

        // resulting width and height of the items
        let innerW: CGFloat = finalW * finalCols
        let innerH: CGFloat = finalH * finalRows

        var x: CGFloat = 0.0
        var y: CGFloat = 0.0

        // loop through, doing the actual layout (setting each item's frame)
        innerContainerView.subviews.forEach { v in

            v.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: finalW, height: finalH)
            x += finalW
            if x + finalW > innerW + 1 {
                x = 0.0
                y += finalH
            }

        }

        // update inner container view's width and height constraints to match
        //    single item width * number of columns
        //    single item height * number of rows
        innerWidthConstraint.constant = innerW
        innerHeightConstraint.constant = innerH

    }

}

// simple custom view with a label in a "content container"
class MyView: UIView {

    // this will hold the "content" of the custom view
    // for this example, it just holds a label
    let theContentView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        return v
    }()

    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .clear
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
        return v
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {
        self.backgroundColor = .clear

        // add the label to the content view
        theContentView.addSubview(theLabel)

        // add the content view to self
        addSubview(theContentView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain the label to all 4 sides of the content view
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContentView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // constrain the content view to all 4 sides of self with 5-pts "padding"
            // so when two views are side-by-side, or over-under,
            // the "content views" will have 10-pts spacing
            theContentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 5.0),
            theContentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -5.0),
            theContentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 5.0),
            theContentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -5.0),

        ])
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm trying to remake this with a storyboard instead of code. I can change the add and remove buttons, the buttonStack, the border view and the outer view and the program still functions how I want it. When I change the inner view to an IBOutlet however, the frame gets shifted so that the top right corner of the inner view is now in the center of the screen and 3/4 of the view is off the screen. Do you know whats going on?

Comment: So I'm trying to implement this into my project with storyboard and the top left corner of the cards is at the middle of the screen, everything else seems to be right I think. Do you think you might be able to take a look at it even though you already got the bounty? The project is at https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/set

Comment: @Sam - couple things... 1) You never resize your `cardViewHolderInnerView`, so its size remains at `[0, 0]`, so the "cards" are outside its bounds (if you turn on `Clip to Bounds` you won't even see the cards). 2) Your first call to `updateViewFromModel()` is in `viewDidLoad()` so the card holder view is not sized yet. 3) Your code is only doing a single pass for tiling, so you're not getting the largest sized cards possible. If you add me as a "Collaborator" on your GitHub repo (my id is "DonMag") I can push changes.

Comment: I know that I'm only getting the single pass, I decided that was good enough for me at this point, just to make the project easier, I may add it later. Where should I add updateViewFromModel, and what would be the best way to resize cardViewHolderInnerView? I would just like to make the changes myself if possible.

Comment: It looks like `updateViewFromModel()` is also filling `self.cardViews`, so call it from `viewDidLoad()` and again from `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. Add `@IBOutlet`s for `cardViewHolderInnerView` width and height constraints (see my example app), and update them after determining card w & h and number of "Cols" and "Rows". Only calc the layout once, after adding the card views... so end your `for index in game.board.cards.indices { ... }` loop before `let (w,h) = cardWidthHeight()`

Comment: Thank you so much, theres still a few small problems, like sometimes there is a row of cards hidden at the bottom, partially on screen, while there really should be another column, I've implemented the second pass and uploaded the modified project to the github.

Comment: @Sam -- A) in `cardWidthHeight()` ... in the first `while` loop, you have the same partial calc as the second loop... first loop needs to be `w = containerWidth / numCols` `h = w * 8.0 / 5.0`. B) when setting the card frames in `updateViewFromModel()` floating-point rounding can cut the columns short... the line needs to be `if x + cardW > innerViewW + 1.0 {`. C) When starting a New Game, you need to clear the existing cards... probably in `resetModel()` add `cardViewHolderInnerView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }`

Comment: @Sam - looks like you also need to clear the card background in `draw( ... )`

Comment: @Sam - this is what I get: https://imgur.com/a/kG8kOc0 ... each image is after a couple "New Game" taps. Top image is current code; second image is with `backgroundColor = .clear`, bottom image is with `backgroundColor = .black` (inside `CardView -> commonInit()`). Currently, `backgroundColor` is `nil`, which results in black background, but it doesn't clear the drawing context, so the previous shapes are still there.